# How do i create pojo for the json response type given below and how do i use in retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, pojo

Then how do I create the POJO for such type and how do I use it in retrofit. My JSON response is of this type. This is like an array and i know how to parse only the simple ones.

```
 ["a",{"a_id":"1","a":"10","n":"100"},
 {"a_id":"2","a":"100","n":"10000"},
 {"a_id":"3","a":"500","n":"5000"},
 {"a_id":"4","a":"1000","n":"100000"},
 {"a_id":"5","a":"5000","n":"500000"}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json)

Comment: Useful Stuff http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: no,its different.. i didnt find any solution for this over ther

Answer (score 1):

For the Pojo Simply use this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, paste response into, and select   Annotation style:Gson, Source type:Json and leave others as default.